# Flutter Listen to of ChangeNotifier class who is a property of a ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I have a class Cart which is ChangeNotifier. It has items as a property which is also a ChangeNotifier.

When I update a property of items it doesn't get reflected immediately.

```
class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Item> _items = [];
  Customer customer;

  setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    customer = customer;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get items => _items;
  
  ...

  removeItem(int index) {
    _items.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ...
}

class InvoiceDetail with ChangeNotifier {
  int id;
  String name;
  double price;
  double qty;

  InvoiceDetail(
      {Key key,
      this.id,
      this.name,
      this.price,
      this.qty = 1,
  })
      : super();

  double get lineTotal => unitPrice * qty - discount;

  increaseQty() {
    qty++
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ...


}
```

When I use incrementQty inside a child component it doesn't get reflected immediately. How to listen to property notifications and fire them too?

Comment: In parent add listener for each item and then in listener notify the parent

Comment: Will you be able to provide a sample please.

Comment: I like using the packages `flutter_hooks` and `hooks_riverpod` to do this. it will allow you to wrap your change notifier in a `ChangeNotifierProvider` and call `useProvider` in your build method to automatically re-build when the change notifier is updated

Answer (score -2):

Like @Selvin mentioned: Add a listener of the child in the parents assigning methods and call `notifyListeners()`:

```
class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Item> _items = [];
  Customer customer;

  addItem(Item item) {
    item.addListener(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
    this._items.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    customer.addListener(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
    this.customer = customer;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

P.S.: Try to make your example simpler and use more common classes. The class InvoiceDetail isn't even Part of `Cart`. Use `Item` or `Customer` instead.